# how to print "before gather" before "after gather" in mpi python mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi, stdout, hpc, mpi4py

Refer to the following gather code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM.WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
stat = MPI.Status()

message = (rank)**2
print "Before Gather ",rank, message

message = comm.gather(message, root=0)

if rank == 0:
        print "After Gather ",rank,message
```

How can I use the **comm.barrier()** function to ensure *the “After” step always comes after all the “Before” steps?*

If I put comm.barrier() before if condition, the results would just be in any order.

I've tried flush and it doesn't work.

Should I specify the send buffer and receive buffer using Gather?

Or, should I try gather everything to one process, then scatter, then gather again?

Any advice is more than welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot.

`stdout` from each MPI tasks are *gathered* and then printed by `mpirun`, and there is no mechanism that enforces any kind of global order.

The only guarantee is that `Before Gather 0 ...` will always be printed before `After Gather 0 ...`

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, to print "before gather" before "after gather". Actually, the thing is, the results always come in a random order, though I put a comm.barrier() before gather. Even sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work here. I am wondering maybe print doesn't produce a stdout......or maybe yes.  Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: well, like i said, there is no guarantee that for `n > 0` `Before Gater n ...` will end up before `After Gather 0` in your output. If you do require this behavior, you cannot rely on `stdout`. if this is just for debugging purpose and you want something that works *most of the time*, you can `flush()` **and** `sleep()` long enough just before or right after `MPI_Gather()`

Comment: Ok I understand it now. Thanks, Gilles.